# How do I schedule a cloud function to update every user in the Firebase Realtime database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I've hooked up cloud scheduler to my project and ready to run everyday. I have data attached to a user that I want to update everyday.

```
likesforday
    uid1
       -Amount : 43
    uid2
       -Amount : 567
```

I need to set all amounts to 0.

I can update one record correctly but I can't figure out how to update every user In the Realtime database. I would also like for it to be an atomic update so it's either all users or none.

There's a lot of guides on using onWrite onCreate, etc... But I need scheduler.onRun everyday with an update to all amounts.

I've tried something like this

```
exports.resetdailytaps = functions.pubsub
  .schedule("every day 00:00")
  .onRun(async () => {
  console.log("starting");

let updates = {};
let qu = database.ref(`/likesforday/{uid}`).orderByChild("amount");
const snap = await qu.once("value");
snap.forEach((child) => {
  updates[child.key] = 0;
  console.log("childkey: " + child);
});

return database.ref().update(updates);
```

and other variations, but cant get it to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important point in your question is:

> I would also like for it to be an atomic update so it's either all
> users or none.

For that you need to use the [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference?authuser=0#update) method, as you do in your question: **Simultaneous updates made with this method are atomic**. Either all updates succeed or all updates fail.

The following will do the trick:

```
  exports.resetdailytaps = functions.pubsub
    .schedule('every day 00:00')
    .onRun(async () => {
      console.log('starting');
      const db = firebase.database();
      const updates = {};

      const snapshot = await db.ref('likesforday').once('value');

      snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
        updates['/likesforday/' + childSnapshot.key + '/Amount'] = 0;
      });
      
      return db.ref().update(updates);
    });
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you worked perfectly. Just had to change from firebase.database() to admin.database and then the firebase.database().ref().update( to admin.database.ref.update(

Thank you so much! @Renaud Tarnec

Comment: Glad I could help you! Yes, you're right: since this code is in a Cloud Function, we need to use the Admin SDK. I'll adapt the answer for clarity and future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any need to `orderByChild` is you are just setting Amount of all the child nodes to 0. Please try running the following code:

```
const updates = []

database.ref("likesforday").once("value").then((snapshot) => {
  Object.keys(snapshot).forEach((user) => {
    updates.push(database.ref(`likesforday/${user}`).update({Amount: 0}))
  })
})

await Promise.all(updates)
```

For the cron, you can also try `0 0 * * *` to run at every midnight.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I added some log statements to your suggestion. 

`.then((snapshot) => {
        console.log("snapshot: " + snapshot);
        Object.keys(snapshot).forEach((user) => {
          console.log("user: " + user);
          updates.push(user.ref.update({ Amount: 0 }));
        });
      })`

Looks like snapshot is an [object Object] and user is _database. Im getting the exception : "cannot read property update of undefined". looks like user.ref is undefined. @Dharmaraj

Comment: This solution will generate an error because `user` does not have a `ref` property. Also, `Promise.all()` **does not ensure that either all users or none are updated**. `Promise.all()` rejects immediately upon any of the input promises rejecting or non-promises throwing an error: all the input promises before the rejected one will have been successfully executed.

Comment: Hey @cdub, can you please try the updated solution ?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec solution worked for me. : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68266531/5900508